# Display all the paths in a graph

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search

I work to a java project and I want to display all the paths in a graph ( this graph is represented using adjacency matrix). I try to use DFS algorithm but how can I display all this paths?

I try this

```
for(int i=0; i<nr; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j<nr; j++)
            dfs(i,j);
```

And the DFS algorithm is this :

```
public static void dfs(int src, int dst) {

        al.add(src);
        size++;
        color[src] = true;
        if (src == dst) {       // tests for base condition to stop
            for (Integer i : al) {
                //     Prints the path
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        for (int I = 0; I < nr; I++) {
            if (matrix[src][I].contains("1")  {
                if (color[I] == false) {
                    dfs(I, dst);        // These lines do
                    color[I] = false;   // main job of backtracking
                    size--;
                    al.remove(size);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If I call the function dfs(2,3) the result is good, but that loop seems doesn't work.

Comment: I have a adjacency matrix - for example this one :
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

And using DFS I want to display all the paths in that graph. 
1->0
1->2->3 ... and so on.

When I  called  dfs (1,3) the result is good : 1->2->3, but i want to call this function for all the combination of the nodes of this graph.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when attempting to find a path, you are confusing two things, both stored in the `color[I]` index.

One, you need something (color will do) to store whether you have visited the node.  It seems your `dfs` routine is well poised to "color" visited nodes, and "uncolor" unvisited nodes.

But what isn't apparent, is that you don't seem to have an adjacency matrix that you are searching.  Can you please point out the line of code where you check that two nodes are connected?  Without some decision to know when it is appropriate to follow a node to another node, you run the risk of simply walking the maximum number of possible interconnections (instead of the interconnections that exist).